# Calculate Precision and Recall

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall

I am really confused about how to calculate Precision and Recall in Supervised machine learning algorithm using NB classifier

Say for example
**1)** I have two classes A,B
**2)** I have 10000 Documents out of which 2000 goes to training Sample set (class A=1000,class B=1000)
**3)** Now on basis of above training sample set classify rest 8000 documents using NB classifier
**4)** Now after classifying 5000 documents goes to class A and 3000 documents goes to class B
**5)** Now how to calculate Precision and Recall?

Please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hi you have to divide results into four groups - 
True class A (TA) - correctly classified into class A
False class A (FA) - incorrectly classified into class A
True class B (TB) - correctly classified into class B
False class B (FB) - incorrectly classified into class B

precision = TA / (TA + FA)
recall = TA / (TA + FB)

You might also need accuracy and F-measure:

accuracy = (TA + TB) / (TA + TB + FA + FB)
f-measure = 2 * ((precision * recall)/(precision + recall))

More here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_.28classification_context.29

Comment: Tom Thanks for the reply.Now how to identify TA,FA,TB,FB?Do i have to manually check all the classified documents or is there some method for it?

Comment: You can run tests for each class separately and calculate correctly classified and incorrectly classified. For example when you run your tests for test documents labeled as A there are two possible classifications for each document: if the classification is A, add 1 to TA, if the classification is B add 1 to FB. Similarly for B: if the classification is A, add 1 to FA and if classification is B add 1 to TB. I hope you understand. :-) Of course you don't have to divide tests into two runs for class A and for class B, you can do this in only one run but I think this is easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks Tom,I understood u really did save my day..This what i was confused of..Now i understood the solution..Thanks once more..

Comment: Tom I again need your help.I would like to know how to calculate f-measure for more than two classes

Comment: Hi, sorry it took me so long to reply. You need to calculate macro F-measure. Have a look at this article: http://rushdishams.blogspot.cz/2011/08/micro-and-macro-average-of-precision.html -Tom

Answer (score 7):

Let me explain a bit for clarity.

Suppose there are 9 dogs and some cats in a video and the image processing algorithm tells you there are 7 dogs in the scene, out of which only 4 are actually dogs (True positives) while the 3 were cats (False positives)

Precision tells us out of the items classified as dogs, how many where actually dogs

> so **Precision = True Positives/(True positives + False positives)** = 4/(4+3) = 4/7

While recall tells out of the total number of dogs, how many dogs where actually found.

> so **Recall = True Positives/Total Number = True Positive/(True positive + False Negative)** = 4/9

---

### In your problem

You have to find precision and recall for class A and class B

For Class A

> True positive = (Number of class A documents in the 5000 classified class A documents)
>
> False positive = (Number of class B documents in the 5000 classified class A documents)

From the above you can find Precision.

> Recall = True positive/(Total Number of class A documents used while testing)

Repeat the above for Class B to find its precision and recall.