# Calculate Precision and Recall for more than 2 classes

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall

Can any one help me out in calculating precision and recall for more than 2 classes.
While googling over the internet i found the following help full URL

[Calculate Precision and Recall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777183/calculate-precision-and-recall)

I want exactly the same available in the above URL using NB classifier except i want precision and recall  for more than 2 classes

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are two different strategies to compute the precision and recall across different classes.

The first option is just to average their values (this is called macro-averaged).

The second option is known as micro-averaging and it is a weighted averaged, where each class importance is defined by its relative number of labelled instances. The more documents in the class the more weight it has.

[This](http://www.bradblock.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/A_Study_on_Thresholding_Strategies_for_Text_Categorization.pdf) article by Yang explains this concepts in detail.

Comment: If possible can you explain me only to calculate precision and recall for individual classes.Like how its been explained in the URL i provided for two classes.I want individual precision and recall for every classes when there are more than two classses