# Calculating Precision and Recall by Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision-recall

I am working with a two class dataset, `2` and `4` where `2` is the positive class and `4` is the negative class (regarding sentiment analysis).

I have a set of predictions from my model, and a set of actual values. I need to determine Precision and Recall for each class (the P and R scores for the positive and negative class).

Code is below:

```
preds = [4, 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  2,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  4,  2]
actuals = [2,   4,  2,  4,  2,  4,  2,  4,  4,  4,  2,  4,  4,  4,  2,  2,  4,  4,  2,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  2]

true_pos = 0
true_neg = 0
false_pos = 0
false_neg = 0
for pred, act in zip(preds, actuals):
    # 2 is positive, 4 is negative

    if(pred == 2 & act == 2):
        true_pos += 1

    elif(pred == 4 & act == 4):
        true_neg += 1

    elif(pred == 2 & act == 4):
        false_pos += 1

    elif(pred == 4 & act == 2):
        false_neg += 1

print("True Positive: ", true_pos)
print("True Negative: ", true_neg)
print("False Positive: ", false_neg)
print("False Negative: ", false_neg)
```

Which yields:

```
True Positive:  1
True Negative:  14
False Positive:  0
False Negative:  0
```

However, I am really stuck on how I am supposed to be calculating these metrics by class. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777183/calculate-precision-and-recall) indicates how to do this for an overall, but not by class.

Ideally, I would end up with an output like:

```
Class 2 P Score: x
Class 2 R Score: x
Class 4 P Score: x 
Class 4 R Score: x
```

but I am not sure how to compute that.

How can I adapt my current logic to check for Precision and Recall scores for each class with the above data?

Comment: Could you show your exact sample inputs and your desired outputs?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by _sample inputs_. Those would be the actual labels and the predicted labels, I think, which are composed in the two lists in the beginning of the program. The desired output would be Precision and Recall score for each class, but the question relates to not knowing how to build a function or logic to compute that.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by 'each class'. What exactly is 'each class'? Can you show sample inputs of 'each class'?

Comment: A class is a label...every single value in the `preds`, or the `predicted class` list, is a prediction of a class. The `actuals` is a list of the ACTUAL classes for a dataset. The two lists exist to simplify the program and provide a minimal, complete, reproducible sample. This would equate to running sklearn's train_test_split on an input dataset...

Comment: Are your sample inputs only going to be boolean in nature? Or can it be multiple predictions/answers? If it is simply boolean in nature, you can just standardise the inputs, else provide a sample input to showcase it

Comment: I am still really confused what you mean by inputs. In calculating the Precision and Recall scores, I will only be doing so with my _predicted_ class values, and _actual_ class values, which will only maintain a `2` or `4` designation, as initially stated in my question. I'm sorry if I seem difficult, I just don't know how else to explain this...

Comment: Can you at least provide your calculations on what your outputs will look like? Putting a `x` there is not effective

Comment: ***That is the question*** - There are no calculations, because I don't know how to set that calculation up to provide those metrics by class.

Comment: Are you familiar with the formula of Precision and Recall? If you are, then you should figure out what you want. Till now, I still do not understand what do you mean by 'provide those metrics by class'. Give an actual example calculation, otherwise, provide a use case in which such calculation will be relevant and used in.

Comment: I don't know what that means either -- which is why I posted here. That is the entire point of my question.

Comment: I assume my answer helped you? Hope it clarified for you what you were looking for. It was the reason why I was initially asking for whether you wanted a binary classification.

Comment: Yeah, the `sklearn` link for `confusion_matrix(preds, actuals).ravel()` is all I really needed. From there I can compute the formulas pretty easily. That is what I was having trouble with. Thanks! @ycx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know which direction to point you in:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html
This should be what you are looking for.

Refer to the wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix
and read up on how to use this.