# I want to calculate Precision, Recall and Accuracy in a dataset

Tags: python, prediction, precision-recall

I have two sets of Data: Predicted and Actual.

An algorithm predicts at max five unique pre-defined parameters that are in Predicted. Assuming the parameters are alphabets from a to z. 
So for one row, I see how many out of these paramaters were predicted correctly.

```
Predicted:

Index P1 P2 P3 P4 P5

1     a  b  c  q

2     g

3     s  f  g  v  t


Actual:

Index P1 P2 P3 P4 P5

1     a  s  q  r  t  

2     g

3     t  v
```

code to generate these dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

predicted = pd.DataFrame.from_records(columns =['P'+str(i) for i in range(1,6)],
                                      data=[['a','b','c','q'],['g'], ['s','f','g','v','t']])


actual = pd.DataFrame.from_records(columns =['P'+str(i) for i in range(1,6)],
                                      data=[['a','s','q','r','t'],['g'], ['t','v']])
```

```
For Row1: Correctly predicted parameters: a,q
For Row2: Correctly predicted parameters: g
For Row3: Correctly predicted parameters: t,v
```

How do I calculate Precision, Recall and Accuracy for the same?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the accuracy here, you just need to count the number of occurrences where the predicted parameter matched the actual parameter, ignoring cases where they were both `None`.
Plenty of ways to do that, I'd take this simple option:

```
accuracy = ((predicted==actual) & (predicted.notna() | actual.notna())).sum().sum() / (predicted.notna() | actual.notna()).sum().sum()
```

You can verify that it fits the desired result (2/11).

precision/recall is a bit trickier for multi-class data - you can do it per label but you certainly don't have enough data here. I'd stick with accuracy for this case...

P.S. I've assumed that your accuracy calculation is pretty straight-forward. If it isn't - it should be specified explicitly in your question...

Comment: This is a just an example of the data, which is quite extensive and has 40 classes. i want to calculate recall and accuracy both. Also, if any of the parameters P1-P5 from the predicted results match any of the parameters, I am considering correct classification, i.e. the order of the parameters doesn't matter.

Comment: If that is the case, please edit your question to be explicit about what is your metric for classification. Also, show what is the expected result for your example. These are standard requirements for a question.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I'm using the number of parameters classified correctly, am unsure how to calculate recall, precision and accuracy.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your problem is not "how to do the code that does the calculation", but "how to define the metric"?

Comment: It is both the things.

Comment: The second is not fitting to Stack Overflow; it's strictly a statistics (or data science) question, and would fit at stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: (Though there are some answers here in StackOverflow - try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777183/calculate-precision-and-recall?noredirect=1&lq=1)